# Why the buff/cache showed in free command is more than which listed in vmstat and meminfo

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16349804     4727520     9075260       13992     2547024    11238920
Swap:      19528700       12284    19516416

$ cat /proc/vmstat
nr_free_pages 2268791
nr_file_pages 502861

$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       16349804 kB
MemFree:         9075360 kB
MemAvailable:   11239020 kB
Buffers:         1063716 kB
Cached:           939312 kB
SwapCached:         8416 kB
```

Why the buff/cache(2547024) showed in free command is more than which listed in vmstat(502861*4=2011444) or meminfo(1063716+939312+8416=2011444)?

```
$ uname -a
Linux OP3020 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ free --version
free from procps-ng 3.3.10
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions and hence it is not the right place for the above problem.  Please post it on ServerFault.com.

Comment: @codeforester: On Linux content of files under `/proc/` is usually closely related with programming needs. Lets leave the question here.

Comment: Possibly more appropriate on [unix.se]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see from sources, free utility accounts slab memory in buffer/cached.

```
kb_main_cached = kb_page_cache + kb_slab;
```

In other words it accounts all things what you might drop by

```
echo "3" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

i.e. including dentry and inode cache

Anyhow, I'am unable to understand why `kb_slab` instead of `kb_slab_reclaimable`, but for me this values are pretty equal.
You can check it by yourself on Ubuntu f.e. `sudo apt-get source procps`